# I doing performance testing using JMeter, but every time I get status fail. What is missing in Test plan?

Tags: jmeter

I am doing performace testing of http://www.google.com. Thread no=10, ramp-up period:10
loop count=10

In config element iI have enter server name as http://www.google.com and port no=80 similar in sampler I entered all data as server name: http://www.google.com and port no :8080 
still it shows failed

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove http:// prefix from [Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

> Server (proxy) Hostname or IP address of a proxy server to perform request. [Do not include the http:// prefix.]

Also port 8080 won't work for google and most sites.

Another option is to put full URL (http://www.google.com) in Path field:

> As a special case, if the path starts with "http://" or "https://" then this is used as the full URL.

Comment: @AshwiniSanap you can accept the answer by click on the V sign to the left of the answer